# Restricting IoT Things to certain topics for publish and subscribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, policy

We are using AWS IoT provisioning templates and policies to create and connect things by claim, which works fine to register the things. Once claimed, we want to apply a MQTT policy that grants the IoT thing access to certain topics, restricting what it can and cannot access. However, I'm failing to get this part to work. I want it to allow the thing to connect to various topics, restricting to only those that match the thingname:

```
v1/connect/<thingname>
v1/update/<thingname>
v1/status/<thingname>
```

our policy is:

```
Allow iot:Connect arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}
Allow iot:Publish arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topic/v1/+/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}
Allow iot:Subscribe arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topic/v1/+/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}
Allow iot:Receive arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topic/v1/+/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}
```

The connect restriction works fine, but the others don't allow me to publish or subscribe. If I replace the :topic.... part with *, I can of course connect but that's not securing the topics.

I've followed the AWS Developer Guide as well as I can manage to do this, but I'm failing.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. AWS IoT Core does not use `+` and `#` as wildcard. You can use `*` and `?` instead.
2. You can use `topicfilter` for `Subscrive`, `topic` for `Receive` and `Publish`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topicfilter/v1/*/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topic/v1/*/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<reg>:<acc>:topic/v1/*/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @masaino, this is what I did in the end. I had failed to realise that I'd fixed it before, the same way you showed, but that the current policies cache for 6-8 minutes after activation of a new one, so I hadn't been giving it long enough to take effect before testing each time. That was the root of my frustrations. Thanks